# Resize application window beyond minimum resize limit

Tags: windows-8

So there is this application whose window will resize alright but will not resize beyond w:489, h:709 dimension. The resize arrow shows alright but when you resize the window beyond the said limits, it flickers as if resizing but restores back to it limit. Any ideas on how to resize it will be much appreciated. I'd like to resize it to say w:318, h:709 to save screen space. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not possible if the programmer has restricted the allowed window sizes.

Comment: Oh really? Hmm, that sounds disappointing. Thanks btw